# Node_Redis HGET resolving to boolean array when using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, node-redis

I've been digging into redis and working on a tiny webapp that uses redis as it's only data storage (I know it's not the intended purpose of redis but I am benefitting from learning the commands and just overall working with redis on Node. I'm using Node_Redis.

**Here's what I want to accomplish (all in redis):**
I am try to retrieve the users using their emails.

**Here's the problem:**
I have a Promise.all call which takes all emails (keys) and maps each to go a HGET command. When the Promise.all resolves I expect it to resolve with an array of user objects, but it ends up resolving to an array of booleans (i.e. [true, true, true]).

Here is the logic for `/users`

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  client.lrange("emails", 0, 1, (err, reply) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    if (reply) {
      Promise.all(
        reply.map(email => {
          return client.hgetall(email, (err, reply) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log("reply for hgetall", reply); // this prints a user object correct, but Promise.all still resolves to boolean array :(
            return reply;
          });
        })
      )
        .then(replies => {
          // replies = [true, true, true ...]
          res.send(replies);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    } else {
      res.send([reply, "reply is null"]);
    }
  });
});
```

I've actually used Promise.all plenty of times, and when I log the reply from redis, it shows the correct object too, so I'm pretty confused at this point. How can I get Promise.all to resolve to an array of User objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `client.hgetall` doesn't return a promise. It's async function and you pass a callback to get a result. You should *promisify* this function to use it in `Promise.all`:

```
...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  client.hgetall(email, (err, reply) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(reply);
  });
});
```

You can do *promisification* manually (as in example above) or can use `Bluebird` or `Q` libraries with their `promisify` and `promisifyAll` methods.